# Is there any way to pin Pivot table or charts in share point?

Tags: pivot-tables

I have prepared a excel sheet and prepared some pivot table based on it. Can we pin it in sharepoint so that I can refer it whenever I want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with SharePoint Online or > Foundation then yeah. It all depends on how you want to implement it. Add the excel file to a doc library and insert it with the excel web part in the business data web parts. Or if you have it in one drive you can grab the embed code from 'share' in the web app and insert it that way.